# Fetch firebase data in a runnable

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an app in which when a user's post gets liked, I want the user to get a notification.
I can use the `ChildValueEventListener` but that is too fast.

I don't want the user to get bombarded with notifications every time a 'like' happens. Because if another user constantly keeps 'liking' and 'unliking' a post, the post author user will be bombarded with notifications.

My plan is to run the `SingleValueEventListener` inside a Runnable/Handler and check for notifications every 20 seconds. Something like this below:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
int delay = 20000; // 20 seconds

handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        databaseRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.hasChild("USER_NOTIFICATION") {
                 // new notification exists - alert user
            }

        handler.postDelayed(this, delay);
    }
}, delay);
```

I have two questions. 1) Is it okay to do this? I mean, is it expensive fetch for data every x seconds? 2) Is it okay to run that piece of code inside a `Service` so that user can still get notifications even when the app is closed or killed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're in one go negating the biggest advantage of the Firebase Database (its realtime updates), and reintroducing a big disadvantage it solves (each time you will now download all data, instead of only getting incremental updating).

You're likely better off instead throttling the number of changes you surface to your users in the client-side code. So use a regular `ChildValueEventListener` and simply throttle the updates on the client.

E.g.

```
public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot snapshot, String previousChildKey) {
  if (System.currentTimeMillis() - lastShownTimestamp > 20000) {

    // TODO: show latest data on screen

    lastShownTimestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
  }
}
```